# SUSE SLES 11 Zypper addrepo succeeds; but repo is not added

Tags: linux, sles, zypper

I am using SUSE SLES 11 = on my server zypper addrepo succceds . however after that when I perform a listing of repositories (using zypper repos -d)  I see no repositries were added. This is driving me nuts . Any suggestions ?

```
zypper addrepo https://myservername/myrepopath myRepoName
Adding repository 'myRepoName' [done]
Repository 'myRepoName' successfully added
Enabled: Yes
Autorefresh: No
GPG check: Yes
URI: https://myservername/myrepopath

 # zypper repos -d
 No repositories defined. Use the 'zypper addrepo' command to add one or 
 more repositories.
```

Answer (score 1):

Oops - I found the reason - my root partition was 100 % full . Its sad that zypper silently reports success . After I created some room on root partition it started working fine

```
 df -h
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/sda1        40G   40G     0 100% /
```

After cleaning root partition - same operation succeeded :-)